# Is an SQL query more "expensive" in terms of memory if there are large columns in the table, even if those columns aren't selected?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Say there is a table. The table is used to keep track of Chapters of a Book. The table has this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE Chapters(
   id           INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
   storyId      INT references Books(id) 
   title        TEXT    NOT NULL,
   body         TEXT    NOT NULL
);
```

Now, in this table, the ***body*** column will hold a large, well, body of text. Imagine how large the average chapter is in the average novel and you'll get a rough idea. It'll hold potentially hundreds of kilobytes (perhaps even a megabyte) of string data in it.

Now, there are of course scenarios where you don't need the "body" of the chapter, but require other things like the Title of it. For instance, if I was trying to build a "book index" of the chapters that are in a book, I'd execute a query like so:

```
SELECT title FROM Chapters WHERE storyId = 1
```

And the query would, of course, return me the title of the chapters for the story. However, would the query use a lot of memory because it has to load the resulting rows (columns and all) into memory, and each row in the table has a "heavy" column (the "body" column)?

I'm asking this because (to my understanding - do correct me if I'm wrong) this is how it works in Document-store databases. Each row (or "document") in MongoDB would have to be loaded into memory first, even if you only wanted to return a single field from it. So if I were to execute a similar query in MongoDB, it would "waste" memory by loading the large "body" field into memory, even if the only field I wanted to return was the "title" field.

Are these concerns the same for most SQL implementations? I'm asking for PostgreSQL in particular, but I would also be interested to know if MySQL does it any differently.

Answer (score 6):

If you're not selecting that column then it shouldn't take up resources. Depending on how the particular type of SQL that you're using works, the extra space might cause larger pages and so the server would have to traverse across a larger amount of disk space to find the rows that you need, but in your example you're selecting by an ID (presumably indexed), so even that wouldn't happen. Even in cases where it does happen, that extra column isn't put into memory, it's just skipped over while the server searches for the rows that you need.

For some variants of SQL, something like a `TEXT` isn't even stored with the rest of the row of data - a pointer is used that points to the spot on the disk where it's actually kept. In those cases you wouldn't even have the issue of larger pages.

Of course, all of this is going to be specific to the internals of the SQL variant that you're using. I'm not an expert in MySQL or PostgreSQL, so anyone who is can correct me if any of my explanation doesn't hold true for those specific implementations of SQL.

Comment: I agree.  Increased IO is going to be the largest source of resource contention here.

Comment: FYI: in PostgreSQL, `text` is not a LOB, but [toasted](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-toast.html) (like any other large value), while in MySQL, `text` is a CLOB. And of course, I agree with the IO cost, but memory shouldn't be affected.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you're not selecting that column it **will** take up resources. In the case if MyISAM tables more of the VFS will be used, and for Innodb more of the buffer pool will be used. A record (whether retrieved from an index or a table) is maintained in its entirety for caching purposes (but in the case of MyISAM the VFS is operating on pages which provide another layer of abstraction, however the entire record is read in one go, but may be evicted from the cache in installments).

Even if it were immediately discarded, there would still be a performance impact - because these are variable length records, the DBMS must advance the handle on the stream to the next record, except for the case where it is using an index to dereference a table, it can't jump right to the correct location (and even if it could, seeks are expensive). i.e. for a full table scan or for an index scan, the size of the record impacts performance. Converting a MyISAM table to use [fixed-length records](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/static-format.html) usually has a marked impact on performance (but don't try this with a table using BLOBs and CLOBs).

A further issue with tables containing records where the size of each record can change significantly is record migration. The records accumulate in a defined order, but on update, a particular record may grow too large to fit in the hole it previously occupied. The record is then migrated to the end of the table. This, too, can have a significant impact on performance and another reason that fixed sized records are faster.

Comment: But fixed-length records cannot be used in cases like the Chapters example I gave, can they? Since the "body" column would be a TEXT column. What is the best-practice "solution" to such a problem, then? To just expect for and pay the price for the expensive queries and move on? Or to split off the "large" column to it's own table ("ChapterBody") so that the "predictable" fields can be accessed easily, and pay the price for the Join when the large field is required?

Comment: No - but you offered your schema as an example - I was merely trying to address the question asked in the title. If, instead of your example, you consider a database of people - (names, addresses, phone numbers etc) including a photograph, then the performance will be better maintained by keeping the photo in a separate table from the textual data. In your example, with nothing other than the PK and FK in addition to the BLOBs there's not much to be gained by splitting, particularly if the title and body will change at the same time.

Comment: OTOH, **depending on how the data is queried** there may be a performance benefit from splitting the chapter and body into separate tables or different rows in the same table.

Comment: The optimal design for any DBMS depends on the frequency and nature of the queries as much as the intrinsic structure of the data.

Comment: Thanks. I will bear that in mind when I design for tables that have very large and variable text columns. In the example I gave, one potential scenario where a query might benefit from spliting a chapter's title and body into separate tables is when you only require the titles of a specific book (a "book index" or chapter directory, as you'd find in any physical book). However, I suppose that querying for an entire chapter (title and body) is something that will happen far more often than simply querying for only the titles of chapters.

Answer (score 2):

In PostgreSQL there is no performance penalty if the large field is more than the physical page size, which is 8kB by default. Rows have to fit on a single physical page so if you have a decent chapter size then you will easily go over that limit. Such large rows can be compressed and/or toasted (yes, like bread).

[TOAST](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-toast.html) stores large fields out-of-line while the other fields are stored in the usual way. This avoids any overhead on I/O etc. while extracting other fields only. The excellent PG documentation says it in more detail:

> This scheme has a number of advantages compared to a more
>   straightforward approach such as allowing row values to span pages.
>   Assuming that queries are usually qualified by comparisons against
>   relatively small key values, most of the work of the executor will be
>   done using the main row entry. The big values of TOASTed attributes
>   will only be pulled out (if selected at all) at the time the result
>   set is sent to the client. Thus, the main table is much smaller and
>   more of its rows fit in the shared buffer cache than would be the case
>   without any out-of-line storage. Sort sets shrink also, and sorts will
>   more often be done entirely in memory.

Comment: Thanks for the link. That is very insightful.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is

1. Yes it does affect performance.

but

2. In most cases the performance wont be effected enough for you to worry about as long as your database is ***healthy.

***My definition of healthy is a) The tables are correctly indexed, the database is correctly defragmented and the database is correctly designed.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-compression-internals.html):

> For tables created in `ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC` or `ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED`, the values of `BLOB`, `TEXT` or `VARCHAR` columns may be stored fully off-page, depending on their length and the length of the entire row. For columns that are stored off-page, the clustered index record only contains 20-byte pointers to the overflow pages, one per column. Whether any columns are stored off-page depends on the page size and the total size of the row. When the row is too long to fit entirely within the page of the clustered index, InnoDB chooses the longest columns for off-page storage until the row fits on the clustered index page. As noted above, if a row does not fit by itself on a compressed page, an error occurs.

This means that most of your `TEXT` fields will go off-page and won't severely affect queries which don't use them.

When you doing a query like this:

```
SELECT  title
FROM    Chapters
WHERE   storyId = 1
```

on a properly indexed database, the following happens:

1. The engine looks up all entries with `storyId = 1` in the secondary index on `storyId`. The index is a B-Tree over the indexed keys and the primary key, in your case `storyId` and `id`. You can think of it as a subset of your table which consists of only two fields: `storyId, Id`, is always sorted on them and is updated whenever the original table is updated. This allows locating the value of any given `storyId` fast.
2. The engine gets all the values of `id` it has found on the previous step, and for each value, looks up the `title` in the table. The tables in `InnoDB` are also B-Tree, that is they are ordered by the primary key, `id`. It's also fast to locate each given record by `id`, as the order is maintained by the engine as you update your table.
3. If `title` is stored off-page, the engine gets the address of the first overflow page and traverses the single-linked list until it gets all the data. If `title` is on-page, then the engine just returns it right away.

Now, remember how I said "fast" on step 2?

How fast it exactly is, depends on the size of your pages.

B-Tree is designed in such way that its depth, that is in how many hops can you locate a page by its `id`, depends on the number of pages (not records) it stores and how long the primary key is.

The means if your records are large (that is there are long columns stored on-page), the PK gets less records per page and hence more pages to hold the same number of records, and the index lookups over PK get less efficient.

However, if the `title` is stored on-page, this is alleviated by the fact you don't need to do one (or more) additional page lookups to get its value.